Maneuvers on path's end point with Navigation2 Smac Lattice planner
I try to tune planner and can not get a proper behavior without the maneuver on end points. I've tried to manipulate with tolerance, penelaties and analytic expansion but could not fix that but I am sure that it's possible to get that.
This thing happens often and it lasts rather longer than that presented on the video (usually there are more tries).
I am using ROS2 humble with setup for differential drive robot of rectangular shape.
Reducing turning radius to smaller values (0.1 m) helps, circular maneuvers are smaller but still they appear.
What could I do to improve the path finishing?

Lattice_primitives config:
{
    "motion_model": "diff",
    "turning_radius": 0.45,
    "grid_resolution": 0.05,
    "stopping_threshold": 5,
    "num_of_headings": 16
}

Navigation parameters:
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 20.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: /lidar/scan
    set_initial_pose: false # Published from script
    always_reset_initial_pose: false
    first_map_only: false
    initial_pose:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      yaw: 0.0

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    navigators: ["navigate_complete_coverage", "navigate_through_poses", "navigate_to_pose"]
    default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share nav2_bt_navigator)/behavior_trees/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    default_coverage_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share opennav_coverage_bt)/behavior_trees/navigate_w_basic_complete_coverage.xml
    navigate_through_poses:
      plugin: "backported_bt_navigator/NavigateThroughPosesNavigator"
    navigate_complete_coverage:
      plugin: "opennav_coverage_navigator/CoverageNavigator"
    navigate_to_pose:
      plugin: "backported_bt_navigator/NavigateToPoseNavigator"
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    plugin_lib_names:
      - opennav_compute_complete_coverage_action_bt_node
      - opennav_cancel_complete_coverage_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
    error_code_names: 
      - compute_path_error_code 
      - follow_path_error_code
      - compute_coverage_error_code

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

coverage_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    default_headland_width: 0.45
    robot_width: 0.525
    operation_width: 0.525
    min_turning_radius: 0.45
    linear_curv_change: 200.0
    coordinates_in_cartesian_frame: true
    default_allow_overlap: false
    default_swath_angle_type: "SET_ANGLE"
    default_swath_angle: 0.0 # We know its aligned for the demo

bt_navigator_navigate_complete_coverage_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True




controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 10.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"] 
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.05

    # RPP parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_regulated_pure_pursuit_controller::RegulatedPurePursuitController"
      desired_linear_vel: 0.5
      lookahead_dist: 1.5
      min_lookahead_dist: 0.6
      max_lookahead_dist: 2.0
      lookahead_time: 1.5
      rotate_to_heading_angular_vel: 1.8
      use_velocity_scaled_lookahead_dist: true
      min_approach_linear_velocity: 0.05
      approach_velocity_scaling_dist: 0.6
      use_collision_detection: true
      max_allowed_time_to_collision_up_to_carrot: 1.0
      use_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: true
      use_fixed_curvature_lookahead: false
      curvature_lookahead_dist: 0.25
      use_cost_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: false
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_radius: 0.9
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_speed: 0.25
      use_rotate_to_heading: true  # allows to follow coverage path better in sharper turns
      allow_reversing: false
      rotate_to_heading_min_angle: 0.785
      max_angular_accel: 3.2
      #max_robot_pose_search_dist: 10.0
      use_interpolation: true

controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      #robot_radius: 0.42
      footprint: "[ [0.336, 0.273], [0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, 0.273] ]"
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        inflation_radius: 1.0
        cost_scaling_factor: 1.5
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /lidar/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /lidar/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      #robot_radius: 0.42
      footprint: "[ [0.336, 0.273], [0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, 0.273] ]"
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /lidar/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /lidar/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    yaml_filename: "map.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerLattice"
      tolerance: 0.25                     # tolerance for planning if unable to reach exact pose, in meters
      lattice_filepath: "$(find-pkg-share robot_navigator)/config/lattice_planner.json" 
      downsample_costmap: false           # whether or not to downsample the map
      downsampling_factor: 1              # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
      allow_unknown: false                # allow traveling in unknown space
      max_iterations: 1000000             # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000    # maximum number of iterations to attempt to reach goal once in tolerance
      max_planning_time: 3.5              # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth, and upsample. Will scale maximum smoothing and upsampling times based on remaining time after planning.
      cost_travel_multiplier: 2.0         # For 2D: Cost multiplier to apply to search to steer away from high cost areas. Larger values will place in the center of aisles more exactly (if non-`FREE` cost potential field exists) but take slightly longer to compute. To optimize for speed, a value of 1.0 is reasonable. A reasonable tradeoff value is 2.0. A value of 0.0 effective disables steering away from obstacles and acts like a naive binary search A*.
      angle_quantization_bins: 64         # For Hybrid nodes: Number of angle bins for search, must be 1 for 2D node (no angle search)
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5       # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0    # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting (in meters). This should be scaled with minimum turning radius and be no less than 4-5x the minimum radius
      minimum_turning_radius: 0.45       # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
      reverse_penalty: 4.0                # For Reeds-Shepp model: penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 0.05                 # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply if motion is changing directions, must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 1.05          # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 2.0                   # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
      retrospective_penalty: 0.015        # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: penalty to prefer later maneuvers before earlier along the path. Saves search time since earlier nodes are not expanded until it is necessary. Must be >= 0.0 and <= 1.0
      rotation_penalty: 0.5              # For Lattice node: Penalty to apply only to pure rotate in place commands when using minimum control sets containing rotate in place primitives. This should always be set sufficiently high to weight against this action unless strictly necessary for obstacle avoidance or there may be frequent discontinuities in the plan where it requests the robot to rotate in place to short-cut an otherwise smooth path for marginal path distance savings.
      lookup_table_size: 20.0               # For Hybrid nodes: Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: true      # For Hybrid nodes: Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.  
      allow_reverse_expansion: false      # For Lattice nodes: Whether to expand state lattice graph in forward primitives or reverse as well, will double the branching factor at each step.   
      smooth_path: true                   # For Lattice/Hybrid nodes: Whether or not to smooth the path, always true for 2D nodes.
      smoother:
        max_iterations: 1000
        w_smooth: 0.3
        w_data: 0.2
        tolerance: 1.0e-10
        do_refinement: true               # Whether to recursively run the smoother 3 times on the results from prior runs to refine the results further

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 200
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

  
velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.5, 0.0, 2.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.5, 0.0, -2.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 5.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -5.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0


Reduce your replanning rate. The feasible planners make a feasible path to the goal from the robot's current position. If your robot can virtually do 'more' than what you've set, so its not following that minimum radius, you can find yourself in a position that the only feasible way to get to the goal is to do a maneuver like that from the planner's perspective.
This can be fixed via:

Reducing or removing your replanning rate (or replan based on event) - of which there are many examples of BTs in Nav2 that do this
Stop replanning when in close proximity to the goal if that path is still valid - fully solve your issue, all the BT nodes exist and are provided by Nav2, you just need to create the BT


Thank you for the response and explaination. Which BT node allows me to check goal promixity? I though that PathLongerOnApproach should work, but currently I am testing it and there is a problem. Since the path from starting point to the end point is usually longer than new replanned maneuver near the end point. I would be thankful for the advice.

It's my current BT Tree: https://pastecode.io/s/em9w4v98

I think you're right, we don't have a BT node today which just returns the distance to the goal using this nav2_util: https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_behavior_tree/plugins/decorator/path_longer_on_approach.cpp#L46. That should be easy enough to create and use though! That would be a good contribution back to Nav2 and then you could use that BT node to check distance to goal, if closer than some threshold, then don't update the path as long as that path is still valid (the rest of those nodes do exist)

I've created and tested the new BT node. I added a pull request https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/pull/4620 please correct me if it is in incorrect form, since it's my first PR to Nav2
The thing to node should be that the RateController frequency should be enought to catch the distance changes or the proximity threshold should be choosen with a some spare

That's exactly the right place, we can continue discussion over there!
